# Using Backbone.iobind (socket.io) with a cluster of node.js servers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I'm using [Backbone.iobind](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind) to bind my client [Backbone models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) over [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to the back-end server which in turn store it all to MongoDB.
I'm using socket.io so I can synchronize changes back to other clients Backbone models.

The problems starts when I try to run the same thing over a cluster of node.js servers.
Setting a session store was easy using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) which stores the session to [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).
But now I can't inform all the clients on every change, since the clients are distributed between the different node.js servers.

The only solution I found is to set a pub/sub queue between the different node.js servers (e.g. [mubsub](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub)), which seems like a very heavy weight solution that will trigger an event on all the servers for every change.

Answer (score 1):

How did you reach the conclusion that pub/sub is a "very heavy weight solution"?
Sounds like you got it right up until that part :-)
Oh, and pub/sub is *not* a queue.

Let's examine that claim:
The nice thing about pub/sub is that you publish and subscribe to **channels/topics**.
So, using the classic chat server example, let's say you have a million users connected in total, but #myroom only has 50 users in it.
When a message is sent to #myroom, it's being published once. No duplication whatsoever.
In most use-cases you won't even need to store it on disk/RAM, so we're mostly looking at network/bandwidth here. And, I mean, you're probably throwing more data (probably over the wire?) to MongoDB already, so I assume that's not your bottleneck.

If you also use socket.io's rooms features (which is basically its own pub/sub mechanism), that means only 5 users will have that message emitted to them over the websocket.
And no, socket.io won't iterate over 1M clients to find out which of them are in room #myroom ;-)
So the message is published once, each subscriber (node.js instance) will get notified once, and only the relevant clients -- socket.io won't waste CPU cycles in order to find them as it keeps track of them when they join() or leave() a room -- will receive the message.
Doesn't that sound pretty efficient and light-weight?

Give Redis a shot.
It's really simple to set-up, runs entirely in memory, blazing-fast, replication is extremely simple, etc.

That's the way socket.io [recommends](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#passing-events-between-nodes) passing events between nodes.
You can find more information/code [here](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis).

Additionally, if MongoDB can't handle the load at any point, you can use Redis as your session-store as well.

Hope this helps!